# Function to convert time difference between two dates into timer format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, functions, datetime, time

Does anyone have a function that converts date difference between two dates into timer format ?

For example:

```
select udf_DateDiffTimer ('2020-05-12 14:12:34','2020-05-12 14:12:35')
```

The result should be char string: `'00:00:01'`   (1 sec)

```
select udf_DateDiffTimer ('2020-05-12 14:12:34','2020-05-12 15:26:55')
```

The result should be char string: `'01:14:21'`   (1 h 14 min 21 sec)

It should not be hard to write it myself, just want to make sure I do not re-invent the wheel

Comment: for anyone who downvote, please explain what is wrong with this Question, so at least I won't create such questions in future...

Answer (score 2):

If you have to go above counting to 24h you could use this

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2020-05-12 15:26:54';
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2020-05-12 15:26:55';
DECLARE @Seconds int = datediff(s,@startdate,@enddate);
SELECT CAST(@Seconds/3600 AS VARCHAR(10))
      + RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(s,@Seconds,0),108),6);
```

[Referenced source](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-convert-seconds-to-time-in-sql)

If you only have to go up to 24h:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2020-05-11 15:26:55';
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2020-05-12 15:26:55';
DECLARE @Seconds int = datediff(s,@startdate,@enddate);

SELECT CASE WHEN @Seconds >= 86400 THEN '24:00:00' 
            ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(s,@Seconds,0),108) 
            END as TimeDifference;
```